# Creating specific amount of points along line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, point-creation

I would like to create a specific amount of points along a line in QGIS. The lines are in different lengths, but I want them with a maximum of 50 points (divide by 50). The tools i've found in QGIS are able to place points in a specific distance along a line or geometry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try ["Points along geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) with changing the *'Distance'* to `$length/50`.

[image: result]

Answer (score 8):

You can create points with Geometry generator or Geometry by expression ([see here how to do that](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) using this expression. In line 3, change `20` to set the number of points you want to create per line:

```
with_variable (
    'no',
    20,
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (0,@no-1,1),
            line_interpolate_point( 
                $geometry, 
                length($geometry) / @no * @element 
                + length($geometry) / @no / 2
))))
```

Points are distributed evenly along each line with the same distance from start- and end-point of the line. Delete the second last line (from `+` to `2`) to get the first point on the start-point of the line.

*Screenshot, showing the variant using Geometry generator - create 20 points per line:*

[image]